# Visual Studio Profiler only shows msvcr110.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, profiling

I am running the CPU sampling profiler in Visual Studio 2012, but at the end the report just says that 99.83% of samples went to msvcr110.dll. In the past, I would see a clear breakdown of which of my program functions were called most frequently. Could somebody please help me with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably don't have the PDB for that dll.  Enable the Microsoft symbol server.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you didn't build with debug information (Linker options->Debugging).

Also check the object files contain debug information (C/C++ options->General->Debug Information Format).
/Zi option creates a pdb file.
/Z7 integrates the debug info into the binary (usually less preferred.)

When debug info is missing, profilers will show you some C runtime function that takes a lot of runtime.

Comment: I switched to debug mode and I am still having the same issue (except now it is msvcr110d.dll). I checked the linker options and I have "Generate Debug Info" set to "Yes"

Answer (score 1):

I've had an issue when the VS 2012 profiler wasn't able to pick up symbols. At the same time the debugger worked well.
It turned out to be Update 5 missing.